# Fatal error: Unsupported operand types - Cake PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

i'm newbie to php, and i begin to cakephp. I make the tutorial, to the official website, but i have an error:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\Users\stagi\my_app_name\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\ErrorHandler.php on line 101

Here my code :

```
 public function __construct($options = [])
    {
        $defaults = [
            'log' => true,
            'trace' => false,
            'exceptionRenderer' => ExceptionRenderer::class,
        ];
        $this->_options = $options + $defaults;
    }
```

I don't understand this problem. Can you explain this to me?

Comment: `var_dump($options);`, what is it?

Comment: Sorry i don't know too, it's the basic code, when I create an application with cake php :/

Comment: In the code, that said : " $options The options for error handling."

Comment: Just add that var-dump in your method, see what value it has. It's probably not an array like you expect it to.

Comment: I can not display it, when I make "echo $options;", the var return is empty :/

Comment: My bad, I tried again with var_dump($options); but the return value is NULL

Comment: If you're trying to append two arrays in this command, there is a better way to do it. Are you trying to merge two array in the below line??
"
    $this->_options = $options + $defaults;
"
If you're trying to merge two arrays, use array_merge() method.

Comment: Check your `config/bootstrap.php` file, that's where by default the `ErrorHandler` class is being constructed. Also check what's in the `Error` key in `config/app.php`, that's where the value that is passed to the `ErrorHandler` class constructer is being obtained from.

Comment: @Bhagirath That's 3rd party vendor code, it shouldn't be modified. Besides, `array_merge()` isn't "_better_", it will trigger an error too when a non-array value is being passed to it.

Comment: could you link the tutorial that you're referring to just so we can have a look at what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved ! It's just a problem with the link connection with my database.
Thanks for answer to me.